# The new Asp.net Identity MVC 5 , can my old asp.net mvc 4 code still work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, form-authentication, role-manager

I have created a full module for managing Roles & Users inside asp.net mvc 4, for example the following action method will create a new Role:-

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult CreateRole(MyRole mr)
        {

            if (Roles.RoleExists(mr.RoleName) || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mr.RoleName)))
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Role already there!!!");

                return View(mr);

            }
            else
            {

                Roles.CreateRole(mr.RoleName);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

        }
```

Now i am planning to upgrade my project to use asp.net MVC 5 , and also i will be working on a new asp.net mvc5 web project. and i checked the new membership classes used inside the asp.net mvc 5 , which seems to use a new `RoleManager`. so does this mean that my old code for managing Roles will no longer work on asp.net mvc 5 , since it uses a new membership module ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend on Membership system which you are using. if you are using ASP.NET Membership, code still works and if you are going to use ASP.NET Identity, code no longer works.

Comment: i am assuming that in case i will start a new asp.net MVC5 web project i will use the new ASP.NET Identity, which seems that it will not work on my old code. but does asp.net mvc5 provides a module for managing Roles, such as Create Role, Edit Role, Delete Role, Assign User To A Role and Un-assign User from a Role ? or i need to create my own module?

Comment: Use the ASP.NET Identity facilities for such actions like creating user, role, ... .